# Probability proof, distribution fn of Y= aX+b

Tags: probability

I am trying to study probability and this is one of the unsolved exercises I encountered. Please help.

Suppose $X$ has distribution function $F$, What is distribution function of random variable $Y$ where $Y$ is defined as $Y = aX+b$

Comment: What does it mean when you say X has distribution function F? Do you mean CDF or PDF?

Comment: Seven questions already, and still no description whatsoever of your thoughts, your attempts, and the like.

Comment: @did If you read all my question, I am trying to study probability on my own. I work, age 40, I am not a student. I explained something similar in one of the earlier questions too.

Comment: @Inquest I mean PDF.

Comment: user: Which part of *thoughts and attempts* do you fail to understand?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Start with $$
   F_Y(y) = \mathbb{P}\left(Y \leqslant y\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(a X + b \leqslant y\right)
$$
If you manage to rewrite the latter as $\mathbb{P}\left(X \leqslant g(y) \right)$ you would establish the relationship between $F_Y(y)$ and $F_X(g(y))$.

Comment: Thanks Sasha, I will try and get back to you.